# IE isn't show favicon on 404 and 500 page only. What is may be wrong?

Tags: internet-explorer, tomcat, spring-mvc, favicon

IE isn't showing favicon for 404 and 500 pages only. What may be wrong?
All other browsers are showing it fine. I use Tomcat 6 and Spring MVC. For showing the icon I used this code:

```
<link href="/img/favicon.ico?rev=@buildRevision@" rel="shortcut icon"/>
```

Thanks:)

Comment: How do you serve the image that is the favicon? Please add some spring config and such.

Comment: Try explaning your question better.

Comment: @Gunslinger Are you need web.xml file part? I'm newbie at Spring.

Comment: @putvande, Ok,I try. Sorry for my bad english. If open existing page, favicon is showing, but if enter invalid url for unexisting  page, page  that loaded in IE browsers isn't have favicon.

Comment: Just to be sure. The page that shows up when you enter an not existing page, that has this code in it too right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. All pages have this code for shwing favicon.

Comment: please make sure that the code end up in the final source. Post you web.xml and spring servlet config.

Comment: @Gunslinger, coode web.xml:lang-xml

Comment: @BEST13, what? edit your answer to include the files. :)

Comment: @Gunslinger, how to do it? My config files so big for past it here. May I use link to SkyDrive for files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have same issue with 500 error page on our site. Favicon is not displayed in IE.
You can check it even with this Stackoverflow page.
On this page IE displays favicon:
[IE isn't show favicon on 404 and 500 page only. What is may be wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016385/ie-isnt-show-favicon-on-404-and-500-page-only-what-is-may-be-wrong)
And if url is changed to be wrong to lead to 404: https://stackoverflow.com/questi
there is no favicon on IE.
But favicon tag is there: 
`<link href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>`

Looks like it is IE behavior.